# Why I'm getting Invalid arguments for the function when using double-quotes?

Tags: command-line, error

I'm trying to insert a filename into text as below:

```
:put=expand("%")
```

but I've the following errors:

> E116: Invalid arguments for function expand(
>   E15: Invalid expression: expand(

Why this doesn't work?

What's most surprising thing is that it works when using single-quote instead, e.g.:

```
:put=expand('%')
```

So I'm trying to understand:

- Is there any differences between using double-quotes or single-quotes? If so, what kind?

I'm using Vim v7.4.

Comment: For assign to variable you should use `let` keyword. `let put=expand("%")`

Comment: @AlexKroll, `:help :put`.

Comment: @romainl Yeh. If you exactly wont to put text into your buffer you should use function like `:call append(line('.'), expand("%"))` it put result of `expand()` line bellow cursor.

Comment: `:put` puts text from register like this `:let @x=expand("%") | put x`

Comment: @AlexKroll, so does `put=expand('%')`.

Comment: @romainl Yes! It's works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- From `:help :put`:

  > The register can also be `=` followed by an optional expression. The expression continues until the end of the command. You need to escape the `|` and `"` characters to prevent them from terminating the command.
- For the difference between `"` and `'` in the context of an expression, see `:help expr-quote` and `:help expr-'`.